# Show CarouselView and CollectionView

Tags: c#, .net, xaml, frontend, maui

If I launch the application, it shows me the Carousel View but not the CollectionView. To display it correctly, I have to delete one even though I want to display both at the same time.
Part of the problem is probably linked to the Grid

The full xaml

```
                <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:root="clr-namespace:Fictum.Mobile"
             x:Class="Fictum.Mobile.TheoryPage"
             xmlns:viewmodel="clr-namespace:Fictum.Mobile.ViewModels"
             Title=""
             BackgroundColor="{AppThemeBinding Light=White, Dark=Black}">

    <ContentPage.Resources>
        <root:BytesToImageConverter x:Key="ToImage" />
    </ContentPage.Resources>
    <ContentPage.Content>
        <ScrollView BackgroundColor="{AppThemeBinding Light=#692A8A, Dark=Black}" >
            <StackLayout Padding="10" >
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <BoxView Grid.Row="0" x:Name="Box" />
                    <SearchBar Grid.Row="1" x:Name="SearchBar" Placeholder="Search by location" TextColor="White"
                               WidthRequest="300" HeightRequest="50" BackgroundColor="#3C184F"/> <!--TextChanged="OnSearchBarTextChanged"-->
                    <ListView Grid.Row="2" x:Name="LocationSuggestionsListView" ItemsSource="{Binding Suggestions}">
                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <ViewCell>
                                    <Label Text="{Binding .}" />
                                </ViewCell>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListView>

                    <ImageButton Grid.Row="0" Source="ic_add.png" x:Name="Plus" Clicked="Plus_Clicked"
                     VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="End" HeightRequest="35" Aspect="AspectFit" />


                    <StackLayout Grid.Row="3" BackgroundColor="{AppThemeBinding Light=Red, Dark=Black}">


                        <ActivityIndicator IsRunning="{Binding IsBusy}" IsVisible="{Binding IsBusy}" Color="#404040" 
                                           HorizontalOptions="Center" />

                        <CarouselView x:Name="ItemsCarouselView" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"
                                      PeekAreaInsets="30" IndicatorView="indicatorView">

                            <CarouselView.ItemsLayout>
                                <LinearItemsLayout
                                          ItemSpacing="0"
                                          Orientation="Horizontal"
                                          SnapPointsAlignment="Center"
                                          SnapPointsType="MandatorySingle" />
                            </CarouselView.ItemsLayout>

                            <CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <StackLayout Padding="10" >

                                        <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                                            <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="OnItemTapped" />
                                        </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>

                                        <StackLayout >
                                            <!--Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalOptions="Center"-->
                                            <Border BackgroundColor="Purple" Stroke="Pink" HeightRequest="300" WidthRequest="300"
                                                    StrokeThickness="2" StrokeShape="RoundRectangle 30,30,30,30">
                                                <Image Source="{Binding Image, Converter={StaticResource ToImage}}" Aspect="Fill" />
                                                <Border.Shadow>
                                                    <Shadow
                                                        Brush="Violet"
                                                        Opacity=".7"
                                                        Radius="100"
                                                        Offset="0,0" />
                                                </Border.Shadow>

                                            </Border>

                                            <!--<VerticalStackLayout>
                                                <Label Text="{Binding Text}" 
                                               Style="{DynamicResource ListItetextStyle}" FontSize="Large" 
                                               TextColor="White" />
                                                </VerticalStackLayout>-->

                                        </StackLayout>

                                    </StackLayout>
                                </DataTemplate>

                            </CarouselView.ItemTemplate>
                        </CarouselView>

                        <IndicatorView x:Name="indicatorView" HorizontalOptions="Center" 
                                       IndicatorColor="Gray" IndicatorSize="8"
                                       SelectedIndicatorColor="White" VerticalOptions="Center" />

                        <Label Text="Recommanded for you" TextColor="White" VerticalOptions="Start" />

                        <CollectionView x:Name="ItemsListView" 
                            ItemsSource="{Binding FilteredItems}"                
                            SelectionMode="None">

                            <CollectionView.ItemsLayout>
                                <LinearItemsLayout ItemSpacing="25" Orientation="Horizontal" />
                            </CollectionView.ItemsLayout>

                            <CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                                <DataTemplate>
                                    <StackLayout Padding="10" >

                                        <StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                                            <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="OnItemTapped" />
                                        </StackLayout.GestureRecognizers>

                                        <Grid HeightRequest="200" WidthRequest="200">
                                            <Border BackgroundColor="Purple" Stroke="Pink" HeightRequest="200" WidthRequest="200"
                            StrokeThickness="2" StrokeShape="RoundRectangle 20,20,20,20" >
                                                <Image Source="{Binding Image, Converter={StaticResource ToImage}}" Aspect="AspectFill" />
                                            </Border>
                                        </Grid>
                                    </StackLayout>
                                </DataTemplate>
                            </CollectionView.ItemTemplate>
                        </CollectionView>

                    </StackLayout>

                </Grid>

            </StackLayout>

        </ScrollView>

    </ContentPage.Content>

</ContentPage>
```

And the ViewModel

```
namespace Fictum.Mobile.ViewModels;

[QueryProperty(nameof(ItemId), nameof(ItemId))]
public class TheoryViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    private string itemId;
    private string text;
    private string description;
    private string image;


    public ObservableCollection<Item> Items { get; }
    public Command LoadItemsCommand { get; }
    public Command AddItemCommand { get; }
    public Command<Item> ItemTapped { get; }
    public Command OnEditCommand { get; }
    public Command<Item> DeleteItemCommand { get; }

    public TheoryViewModel()
    {

        Title = "Browse";
        Items = new ObservableCollection<Item>();
        LoadItemsCommand = new Command(async () => await ExecuteLoadItemsCommand());

        ItemTapped = new Command<Item>(OnItemSelected);

        AddItemCommand = new Command(OnAddItem);
        OnEditCommand = new Command(OnEditItem);
        DeleteItemCommand = new Command<Item>(OnDeleteItem);
    }

    async Task ExecuteLoadItemsCommand()
    {
        IsBusy = true;

        try
        {
            Items.Clear();
            var items = await GetItemsAsync(true);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex);
        }
        finally
        {
            IsBusy = false;
        }
    }

    public string Id { get; set; }
    public int? UserId { get; set; }
    public bool IsUpdated { get; set; }

    public string Text
    {
        get => text;
        set => SetProperty(ref text, value);
    }

    public string Description
    {
        get => description;
        set => SetProperty(ref description, value);
    }

    public string Image
    {
        get => image;
        set => SetProperty(ref image, value);
    }

    public string ItemId
    {
        get
        {
            return itemId;
        }
        set
        {
            itemId = value;
            LoadItemId(value);
        }
    }

    public async void LoadItemId(string itemId)
    {
        try
        {
            var item = await DataStore.GetItemAsync(itemId);
            Id = item.Id;
            Text = item.Text;
            Description = item.Description;
            UserId = item.UserId;
            IsUpdated = item.IsUpdated;
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine("Failed to Load Item");
        }
    }

    private async void OnEditItem(object obj)
    {
        var selectedItem = (Item)obj;

        await AppShell.Current.GoToAsync($"{nameof(UpdateTheoryPage)}",
            new Dictionary<string, object>
            {
                ["TheoryItem"] = selectedItem,
            });
    }

    private async void OnDeleteItem(Item item)
    {
        try
        {
            Items.Remove(item);

            await DeleteItemAsync(item.Id);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Debug.WriteLine(ex);
        }
    }

    private async void OnAddItem(object obj)
    {

    }

    async void OnItemSelected(Item item)
    {
        if (item == null)
            return;
    }

    public async Task<IEnumerable<Item>> GetItemsAsync(bool forceRefresh = false)
    {
        using (var httpclient = new HttpClient())
        {
            httpclient.BaseAddress = new Uri(AppSettings.UrlApi);

            string oauthToken = await SecureStorage.Default.GetAsync(AppSettings.AuthToken);
            httpclient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", oauthToken);
            int loginUserId = Convert.ToInt32(await SecureStorage.Default.GetAsync(AppSettings.UserId));
            var requestUri = "api/v1/Theories/all";

            var response = await httpclient.GetAsync(requestUri);

            var content = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            var requestURI = $"api/v1/Users/GetUser/{loginUserId}";
            var response2 = await httpclient.GetAsync(requestURI);
            var userContent = await response2.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                var data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<TheoriesModel>>(content);
                var userData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UsersModel>(userContent);

                // Get the list of block user IDs
                List<int> blockUserIds = userData?.Blocked_Users?.ToList() ?? new List<int>();

                foreach (var d in data)
                {

                    if (d.UserId != loginUserId && !blockUserIds.Contains((int)d.UserId))
                    {
                        var itemId = d.Id.ToString();

                        var item = new Item
                        {
                            Id = itemId,
                            Text = d.Name,
                            Description = d.Description,
                            Image = d.Images?.Blob ?? string.Empty,
                            UserId = d.UserId,
                            IsUpdated = loginUserId == d.UserId,
                            GroupId = d.Group_id,
                        };
                        Items.Add(item);
                    }
                }
            }

        };

        return await Task.FromResult(Items);
    }

    public async Task DeleteItemAsync(string itemId)
    {
        using (var httpclient = new HttpClient())
        {
            httpclient.BaseAddress = new Uri(AppSettings.UrlApi);

            string oauthToken = await SecureStorage.Default.GetAsync(AppSettings.AuthToken);
            httpclient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", oauthToken);
            var requestUri = $"/api/v1/Theories/{itemId}";

            var response = await httpclient.DeleteAsync(requestUri);

            if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Item deleted successfully");
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Failed to delete item");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to add Grid.Row in certain places except that I don't understand it because there is too much detail

[image]

[image]

Comment: both are inside of a StackLayout, so assigning a Grid.Row value doesn't do anything.  You most likely need to assign HeightRequest values to both, or use a different container.  Since a CollectionView can have a variable height, placing it inside a StackLayout can be problematic.

Comment: If you talk about the stacklayout before the grid, I removed it but nothing changes, and the one with the grid.Row = 4, I cannot remove it because it contains parameters

Comment: I mean that `<CollectionView Grid.Row="6"` does nothing, because it is not a child of the `Grid`

Comment: Yes I deleted it, but that doesn't solve anything

Comment: That was only one of the suggestions I made

Answer (score 0):

Because your page displays a bit too much content, one screen can't be displayed.
So, you can try to add a `ScrollView` to the outermost element.

```
<ScrollView>
    <StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">

        <!--  For brevity, omit the other code  -->

   </StackLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Besides, please remove the `HeightRequest` property for element `StackLayout` (`HeightRequest="600"`) below `ImageButton`.

```
    <ImageButton Grid.Row="0" Source="ic_add.png" x:Name="Plus" Clicked="Plus_Clicked"
                     VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="End" HeightRequest="35" Aspect="AspectFit" />

   <StackLayout Grid.Row="4" BackgroundColor="{AppThemeBinding Light=#692A8A, Dark=Black}"  VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand" HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" Margin="0">
```

Comment: The scrollView allowed you to see at the bottom, but the elements are too separated and I can't find a way to bring them together (I added more information)

Comment: Is the above code the latest code? I didn't have the problem you mentioned when I used the code above.

Comment: I just changed the color but it's 99% the same

Comment: I can provide you with the github, but to recreate at least, reproducible example is very complicated because the code is long

Comment: If you can, could you please post the full xaml code and view model of your page?

Comment: Of course, It's done

Comment: You can recheck if the `Items` could get the data correctly. I added some fake data on my side, and there is no such problem.

Comment: I put a default image and like in the screenshot that I added it didn't change anything on my side...

Comment: It's weird that this problem doesn't come up on my end.